# Unable to convert openoffice documents using docsplit resulting in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux, openoffice.org, docsplit

I have installed the docsplit gem and been able to convert PDF documents. However when it comes to splitting openoffice documents such as powerpoint and word files, I get the following error:

```
Exception: Command
/usr/local/bin/docsplit pdf /tmp/tmpzuk5gf/dump.ppt --output /tmp/tmpzuk5gf
finished with return code
1
and output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /usr/lib/openoffice
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .usr.lib.openoffice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: /usr/lib/openoffice. Program will exit.
```

I have already checked that the `/usr/lib/openoffice` folder is available.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Is it included in your classpath ?

Comment: The result of my `echo $PATH` is as follows: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`

Comment: Do these folders have : openoffice related jar files ?

Comment: Command `whereis openoffice` results are `openoffice: /usr/bin/openoffice.org /etc/openoffice /usr/lib/openoffice /usr/share/openoffice /usr/share/man/man1/openoffice.1.gz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `docsplit 0.7.2` with `OpenOffice` and `Ubuntu 10.04`. However, version 0.7.0 onward seems to have a preference for `LibreOffice` over `OpenOffice`. So I downgraded my docsplit to version 0.6.4 and it works OK with OpenOffice. I can now run the commands successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have using `docsplit 0.7.2` with openoffice and `ubuntu 12.04` all is OK.

In previous time I have used `ubuntu 10.04` and sometimes converting were breaking with similar error, but i had tried again and in most cases converting were completed successfully.